# Angular 14 to 15 upgrade unit tests are failing

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to upgrade Angular 14 to Angular 15, and have been following the Angular Upgrade guide. My application builds and the I can run ng serve and the site works, but I continually get errors when running the unit tests.

The first issue I encountered was a typescript error:

```
Debug Failure. Unexpected node.
Node HeritageClause was unexpected.

at classElementVisitorWorker (../../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:93950:37)
at ../../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:93917:92
at saveStateAndInvoke (../../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:93773:27)
at ../../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:93917:45
at visitArrayWorker (../../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:91402:48)
at Object.visitNodes (../../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:91366:23)
at visitClassDeclaration (../../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:94199:117)
at visitTypeScript (../../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:94067:28)
at visitorWorker (../../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:93829:24)
at sourceElementVisitorWorker (../../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:93854:28)
```

I made changes to update jest, webpack and tslib and did not receive the Node HeritageClause failure, but I encountered ReferenceError: Window is not defined:

```
FAIL   user-management  libs/user-management/src/lib/user-management.module.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: Window is not defined

      20 |
      21 |   constructor(
    > 22 |     @Inject(WINDOW) private readonly window: Window,
         |                                              ^
      23 |     private readonly componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
      24 |     private readonly applicationRef: ApplicationRef,
      25 |     private readonly injector: Injector

      at Object.<anonymous> (../common-ui/src/lib/window/window-manager.service.ts:22:46)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../common-ui/src/index.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/user-management.module.ts:17:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/user-management.module.spec.ts:2:1)
```

I am on currently on Node version 18.10.0, and Angular version 15.2.10.

My Angular application is using the following libraries and testing framework:

- ngrx
- nrwl
- rxjs
- jest

I currently have the following in my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^15.2.1",
  "@angular/animations": "15.2.10",
  "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
  "@angular/common": "15.2.10",
  "@angular/compiler": "15.2.10",
  "@angular/core": "^15.2.10",
  "@angular/forms": "15.2.10",
  "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.10",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.10",
  "@angular/router": "15.2.10",
  "@azure/app-configuration": "^1.5.0",
  "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.17.0",
  "@microsoft/applicationinsights-common": "^2.8.16",
  "@microsoft/applicationinsights-core-js": "^2.8.16",
  "@microsoft/applicationinsights-properties-js": "^2.8.16",
  "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.8.16",
  "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.17",
  "@ngrx/effects": "^15.4.0",
  "@ngrx/entity": "^15.4.0",
  "@ngrx/router-store": "^15.4.0",
  "@ngrx/store": "^15.4.0",
  "@nrwl/angular": "^14.8.9",
  "@schematics/angular": "^15.2.10",
  "@types/quill": "^2.0.14",
  "angular-auth-oidc-client": "^14.1.5",
  "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
  "core-js": "^2.6.12",
  "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
  "fontawesome-pro": "^5.14.0",
  "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
  "minimist": "^1.2.8",
  "ngx-dropzone": "^3.1.0",
  "ngx-filesaver": "^13.0.0",
  "ngx-mask": "^13.2.2",
  "ngx-quill": "^16.2.1",
  "quill": "^1.3.7",
  "rxjs": "6.5.5",
  "tslib": "^1.14.1",
  "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
  "zone.js": "0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^15.0.0",
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "15.2.10",
  "@angular/cli": "^15.2.10",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.10",
  "@angular/language-service": "15.2.10",
  "@ngrx/schematics": "15.4.0",
  "@ngrx/store-devtools": "15.4.0",
  "@nrwl/cli": "^14.8.9",
  "@nrwl/cypress": "^14.8.9",
  "@nrwl/jest": "^14.8.9",
  "@nrwl/tao": "^14.8.9",
  "@nrwl/workspace": "^14.8.9",
  "@politie/angular-testcafe-builder": "^2.0.5",
  "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
  "@types/node": "14.14.33",
  "buffer": "^5.7.1",
  "codelyzer": "6.0.0",
  "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
  "dotenv": "10.0.0",
  "eslint": "^8.56.0",
  "gherkin-executor-typescript": "^1.1.0",
  "jasmine-marbles": "~0.8.3",
  "jest": "^29.7.0",
  "jest-junit": "^15.0.0",
  "jest-preset-angular": "^13.1.6",
  "lcov-result-merger": "^3.3.0",
  "openssl-self-signed-certificate": "^1.1.6",
  "prettier": "^2.5.1",
  "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
  "testcafe": "^2.6.2",
  "testcafe-reporter-xunit": "^2.2.3",
  "testcafe-tools": "^1.1.18",
  "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
  "ts-node": "9.1.1",
  "tslint": "6.1.3",
  "typescript": "^4.9.5",
  "webpack": "^5.78.0"
},
```

I am not sure if this is an issue with jest or that I'm installing the wrong packages, or could this be a bigger issue?

Comment: window is never defined in node. There is no window if there is no browser. Try wrapping it around or mocking it to solve the issue

Comment: "Window is not defined" was not an issue with Angular 14, only after the upgrading to 15.  Is there something different with the Angular 15 upgrade that now requires mocking the window service in the spec files?  I did attempt to resolve it that way but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you didn't encounter this sooner, because it isn't like Window is going to be defined when using Jest since it is running in NodeJs and not the browser.  I would assume your tests addressed this appropriately, but now something about the upgrade is being more strict in its typings.

To get around this you could derive a *WindowType* from the return type of your **WINDOW** injection token, and then use that type in your service.  Depending on what's building the test, the type will either be determined to be either the Window type or whatever you used for a fallback:

```
export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken('Global window object', {
  factory: () => typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : undefined
});
export type WindowType = typeof WINDOW extends InjectionToken<infer T> ? T : never;
```

Use the new *WindowType* in your service.

```
constructor(
  @Inject(WINDOW) private readonly window: WindowType,
  /* ... */
)
```

Alternatively, making window the type of the **defaultView** property of *Document* should also work since it *is* in nodeJs.

```
constructor(
  @Inject(WINDOW) private readonly window: Document['defaultView'],
  /* ... */
)
```